# How can I get android device Unique ID?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)

I used below code to get android device IMEI and How can I change below code to get android device Unique ID.

```
String getDeviceID1(TelephonyManager phonyManager){
    String id = phonyManager.getDeviceId();
    if (id == null){
        id = "not available";
    }
    int phoneType = phonyManager.getPhoneType();
    switch(phoneType){
        case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE:
            return "" + id;

        case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM:
            return "" + id;

        case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA:
            return "" + id;

        /*
        *  for API Level 11 or above
        *  case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_SIP:
        *   return "SIP";
        */

        default:
            return "" + id;
    }

    //I used to show IMEI 

    TextView textDeviceID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.deviceid);
    //retrieve a reference to an instance of TelephonyManager
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    textDeviceID.setText(getDeviceID1(telephonyManager));
}
```

Comment: you want to change IMEI ???? why ?

Comment: @Eric, its not a Duplicate Quetsion, its **Not a Real Question**.

Comment: @Lucifer The way he words it, it sounds like he wants to change it to get a *different* unique device ID, which is covered in that post... So, I guess it depends how you interpret the question. Either way, a vote to close is a vote to close.

Comment: @Lucifier : He doesn't want to change IMEI. He means to say that he has successfully implemented the program to get the IMEI. He is asking for what to change in the program to get Unique device ID instead of IMEI.

Comment: @Lucifer I mean, I don't wanna show anymore IMEI in my app. I have to show android unique device id.

Comment: **IMEI** it self is unique id, then what else you need ?

Comment: @Lucifer IMEI is better than Android Unique device id?

Comment: @ArnoHlaMoe, it depends on your requirement.

Comment: @Eric, not duplicate question. I read Is there a unique Android device ID?..Post but I don't know how to change in my script. I am beginner. Please help me.

Comment: @Eric , I believe now you are right :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Android, you can get three different Unique Ids.

- IMEI ( which you have in your code already )

  ```
  TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  String id =  (getDeviceID1(telephonyManager));
  ```
- [Device ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/996493)

  ```
  String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                  Secure.ANDROID_ID);
  ```
- Bluetooth Address ( this will also be unique for each device )

  ```
  private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;

  // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
  mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  String deviceMacAddress = mBtAdapter.getAddress();
  ```

Comment: Thanks. how can I change Bluetooth Address in my script?

Comment: what do you mean by **change** , I am not getting you properly.

Comment: I mean where I should add bluetooth address script to my script.

Comment: of course, add it where you required a unique id.

Comment: CAUTION!!!! According to the documentations, The value of `ANDROID_ID` may change if a factory reset is performed on the device